# New SD card for 3DS XL

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I plan on buying buying a new Nintendo 3DS XL and a 32GB SD card right off the bat for it.

Can I use the new SD card immediately or is there pre-loaded software or data that may need to be transferred?

Comment: my one had per-loaded software and i only got mine a couple of weeks ago, but it's just a couple of apps, mostly useless to me

Comment: For anyone considering going beyond 32 GB: I initially thought it would be impossible, since Nintendo stated the 3DS supports SDHC (which only goes up to 32 GB), but not SDXC (which can go up to 2 TB). Actually, the 3DS *does* support SDXC cards, according to [this article](http://lofi-gaming.org.uk/blog/2013/10/25/updated-how-to-upgrade-your-3ds-sd-card-to-64gb-and-beyond/). Enjoy ;)

Comment: So I bought a red and black 3DS xl with pokemon y an a 32GB Sandisk elevate 30mb capacity memory stick, I didn't copy over anything but I formatted and used the the new card and it seems to be working so far

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you can change SD cards as long as you are willing to move the data to your new card, and **you will not lose any data**.

Here is a link to the [official nintendo guide](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/3ds/en_la/ht_settings.jsp?menu=data%20management&submenu=ctr-ht-settings-transfer-data-between-sd) to migrating SD cards.

You just have to copy stuff over. Also make sure your new card is formatted as FAT32, or you could just use your 3DS to format it.

Comment: Thx for the link to the guide! good tip there!